# How to get all Django REST Framework permission classes?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

After starting a Django shell using `./manage.py shell` I can't see any of the custom permission subclasses in the application:

```
In [1]: from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission                                                                                                                                  
In [2]: BasePermission.__subclasses__()                                                                                                                                                        
Out[2]: 
[rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny,
 rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated,
 rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser,
 rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
 rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissions]
```

**How can I get all the permission classes, including the custom ones?**

I'm writing a custom management command to list all existing permissions and how they are used, so **I need some way to load my entire application rather than importing each file separately.**

Comment: When you say custom command do you mean a django management command?

Comment: Are your permission classes in the `permissions.py` file of each app, or are they spread across various files? i.e. are there any `views.py` files that contain a custom permissions class definition?

Comment: @A.J.Parr I think they are all in a permissions.py, but I most definitely don't want to unsafely assume that that will always be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is happening because you haven't imported those subclasses, so the python interpreter is not aware of there being any custom subclasses of `BasePermission`.

I initially tested this myself using the `python manage.py shell_plus` command from the [`django-extensions`](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) package, which imports all your models when it starts the shell. Then when I ran `BasePermission.__subclasses__()` it listed all my custom permissions.

Then I tried `python manage.py shell`, ran the same code, and the result was the same as yours.

So if you have all your permissions in a single file, or a file pattern such as `<app_folder>/permissions.py`, you should import all those permissions files (to the effect of `from app_folder.permissions import *`) and then try `BasePermission.__subclasses__()`.